# React Helmet Cycling through titles as page loads

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

I have a react application and I am using react helmet to set the title of the page. Unfortunately, as the page loads I am seeing 3 different titles displayed locally. I don't want this for 2 reasons, one it looks weird and two, I'm not sure which one Google will actually use.

In the documentation for React-Helmet it says that you can add it to child components to change the values that were there originally which is what I did.

In index.html I have `<title>Default Title</title>`

In PageLayout.jsx I have `<title>My React Project</title>`

In Weather.jsx (one of my site's pages) I have `<title>Weather</title>`

As the site loads I see Default Title, then "My React Project", finally, "Weather". How do I make it only say "Weather" without removing the default title?

```
return (
    <>
    <Helmet>
        <title>Hello</title>
    </Helmet>
    </>
);
```